# Freestyle: how to make uneven messy outlines

Tags: bezier-curves, freestyle, 2d

Yesterday, I saw this below thread by Snoob Dog, thus inspiring ideas for 2d animators. Awesome answers therein.

[Freestyle: control the Thickness of stroked curve using Radius?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119117/freestyle-control-the-thickness-of-stroked-curve-using-radius/119449#119449)

Now, I have new ideas - new artistic outlines. 
Is it possible to do any of messy uneven lines like those below? And also to vary their thickness? Could particles be used to make smudgy outlines? 
[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: I think that Freestyle is what you are looking for, you can add noise on stroked borders but, in this case, it will be hard to have a variation in the thickness even if it is possible

Comment: There are lots of clues [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80242/how-can-i-improve-the-realism-of-my-pencil-texture-lines-in-freestyle) and a few [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116443/sharpen-the-ends-of-freestlye-lines/116556#116556)...  you can texture, overdraw, add noise, set tips .. all sorts..

Comment: I have found something in Youtube. My jaw dropped when I saw this guy's works on scraggly lines. It is a MUST-SEE.  https://youtu.be/lsXb5ywrg_I.